# Get input name from request, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, request

In the laravel how can we made something like this?
For example if we write dd($request); in the controller:

```
 "slug_en" => "english_slug_here"
 "lang_en" => "english"
 "slug_es" => "spanish_slug_here"
 "lang_es" => "spanish"
```

If i must use "english", simply i can use $request->lang_en;
But what if i know just "english" and want to know input name?

```
$request->X = "english";
```

I want to X right here. I need to set language system with dynamically, but i stuck right here. If can anybody help me, i'll glad so much. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$x = array_search ('english', $request->all());
```

Comment: this worked like a charm. I have 2nd question. if we have two input. title and slug for example. Probably these are gonna same. How can we get second input? I mean, title_en="foo", slug_en="foo". Your way is return one of them. How to get second or third? Can we use this like that? array_search('english', $request->all(), 2); ? I hope, i could express myself.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$x = array_keys ($request->all(),'english');
```

returns all the keys having value english

if given only the array returns all the keys. The search field is included as a second parameter to get keys for the given search value and there is a optional third parameter strict which may be either true or false, if set strict validation occurstrue

Comment: Please chek http://am1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php
Your answer is wrong

Comment: Wrong again. [Parameters order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220097/get-input-name-from-request-laravel#answer-52220185).